# Limit Spotlight to mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, spotlight

The thing is I hate Spotlight like every software burning my cpu for no reason when I am working and I could put my cpu to better use BUT it is required to search in mail bodies with Mail so I still keep it...

What I really want to do is stop Spotlight to index anything but my emails, is there a way to do that ?

I already added the biggest folders to the ignore list but it does not seems to be enough since as I am writing this mds is happily using between 10% and 30% of my cpu :/

Comment: Have you turned off time machine (to test this) and reboot? That is the largest consumer of mds in my experience...

Comment: time machine is already turned off, I do not use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If mds is continually using that much CPU then something else is wrong, that's not usual behaviour. Once the index is created, it's incrementally updated and shouldn't be using that much CPU at all.

However, you could try telling Spotlight only to display Mail Messages in searches. You'll find that option in System Preferences in the Spotlight section. (edit) This doesn't actually stop Spotlight indexing those items, but it wont display them in results.

[image: SPotlight prefs]

**I think you have a more fundamental problem here with Spotlight that should be resolved. Try deleting and recreating the index with the following command:**

```
sudo mdutil -i on -Evsa
```

Comment: I agree with Macaco.  I've adjusted Spotlight to only index documents, folders, mail, contacts, applications and PDFs.  My MDS is 0% at the moment.

Comment: Just to be clear - toggling search results doesn't prevent this data from entering the index. It simply filters the results from the spotlight ui in the menu bar. Explicitly adding folders to the privacy tab _does_ exclude them from indexing altogether.

Comment: The list is only used for display purpose as pointed by bmike, even knowing that I unchecked everything except Applications since that is the only thing I may want to access with spotlight.

Comment: You might want to include in your answer how to shutdown the mds service, force a re-index and restart it safely. It would make for a much better answer.

Comment: @cksum done! :)

Comment: I ran your command, wait and see ;)

Comment: It looks like reindexing the database works more or less, it took a while but now it looks it's stabilized.

Comment: Is there any way to see what is indexed somewhere so I can add more in ignore list ?